# Are chemical rockets really beyond 60% efficient?

Tags: physical-chemistry, rocket-science, propulsion

Are chemical rockets really beyond 60% efficient?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_engine
“Rocket engine nozzles are surprisingly efficient heat engines for generating a high speed jet, as a consequence of the high combustion temperature and high compression ratio. Rocket nozzles give an excellent approximation to adiabatic expansion which is a reversible process, and hence they give efficiencies which are very close to that of the Carnot cycle. Given the temperatures reached, over 60% efficiency can be achieved with chemical rockets.”

If they are really this efficient why can’t we have [Aeopiles](https://www.google.com/search?q=Aeolipile&client=ubuntu&hs=Qqs&sxsrf=ALeKk03dTPba5DbpbhV4OYwxJM1sT1FupQ:1614869193692&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT5ZfF8JbvAhUGOs0KHchWANYQ_AUoAnoECBEQBA&biw=1096&bih=544) with hydrogen oxygen rockets on them, for high power to weight ratio electric generators, with similar efficiency as fuel cells? And we might not need precious metals for it. I don't mean we should try making a rocket-pile the size of a pair of opposing shuttle main engines but something much smaller like a hydrogen/air detonation engine. It would look something like the ancient Alexandrian engineer's version of the Aeopile.

Answer (score 2):

> why can’t we have [aeolipiles] with hydrogen oxygen rockets on them ...

Because efficiency is not the only consideration when designing a practical engine or generator. A rocket powered aeolipile would be:

- An engineering nightmare - extreme temperatures and pressures in combustion chambers that are rotating at high speed
- Extremely noisy due to supersonic exhaust
- Very dangerous - volatile fuel components and high temperature exhaust going in all directions

Comment: excellent points, +1. -NN

Comment: Can a rocket be 60% efficient at conveying force to a free moving payload?